# How to create a chain of Hadoop job without using OOzie

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to create a chain of three Hadoop jobs, where the output of one job is fed as the input to the second job and so on. I would like to do this without using Oozie.

I have written the following code to acheive it :-

```
public class TfIdf {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        TfIdf tfIdf = new TfIdf();
        tfIdf.runWordCount();
        tfIdf.runDocWordCount();
        tfIdf.TFIDFComputation();
    }

    public void runWordCount() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Job job = new Job();


        job.setJarByClass(TfIdf.class);
        job.setJobName("Word Count calculation");

        job.setMapperClass(WordFrequencyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordFrequencyReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("input"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("ouput"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

    public void runDocWordCount() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Job job = new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(TfIdf.class);
        job.setJobName("Word Doc count calculation");

        job.setMapperClass(WordCountDocMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountDocReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("output"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("ouput_job2"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

    public void TFIDFComputation() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Job job = new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(TfIdf.class);
        job.setJobName("TFIDF calculation");

        job.setMapperClass(TFIDFMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TFIDFReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("output_job2"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("ouput_job3"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

However I get the error:

```
Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/output
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What does hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/ show?

Comment: [cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera

Found 4 items

drwx------   - cloudera cloudera          0 2013-10-31 01:37 /user/cloudera/.Trash

drwx------   - cloudera cloudera          0 2013-11-13 11:02 /user/cloudera/.staging

drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2013-11-07 19:20 /user/cloudera/input

drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2013-11-13 11:02 /user/cloudera/ouput

Comment: what about using hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/ instead?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is coming a little late, but... It's just a simple typo in your dir names. You've written your 1st job's output to dir "ouput", and your 2nd job is looking for it in "output".